# Can I use variables in crontab file?

Tags: cron

I mean I want to use this variable at "minute to wday" in the following.

```
minute   hour    mday    month   wday    who command
```

Because I want to set these values in some configuration file and want to use those time spans here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so that you can use variables as placeholder's there. Following is allowed

1. Numbers, ranges as hyphen`-` separated number which can again be separated using comma `,` example:

   for day-of-month you can write `2-4,8-10`, if you need to run the job from 2<sup>nd</sup> to 4<sup>th</sup> and 8<sup>th</sup> to 10<sup>th</sup> day of month.
2. One of the following pre-defined ones

> ```
> @reboot     :    Run once after reboot.
> @yearly     :    Run once a year, ie.  "0 0 1 1 *".
> @annually   :    Run once a year, ie.  "0 0 1 1 *".
> @monthly    :    Run once a month, ie. "0 0 1 * *".
> @weekly     :    Run once a week, ie.  "0 0 * * 0".
> @daily      :    Run once a day, ie.   "0 0 * * *".
> @hourly     :    Run once an hour, ie. "0 * * * *".
> ```

If you need something dynamic for a large list of job to be created, I suggest create a shell script that will dump the required crontab timings, which you can place in the crontab file.

[unix man page for crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5)

Comment: Thanks mtk. i will write a script to dump the entire entry into the crontab file.
Is there any way to remove a particular entry from crontab file.(i mean using any command other than writing the script)

Comment: `crontab -r` removes all the entries. Just edit the `crontab` to delete particular entries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use standard syntax for crontab and check for user/weekday inside your script.

Comment: Er. What script?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek The shell snippet that runs at the specified time(s).